# Monet DB server start up error BBPcheckbats: cannot stat file

Tags: server, monetdb

Am using monet DB version v 2.0.I uploaded a pipe delimited csv file into monet DB uing copy into and it completed successfully.However when I tried the query "select * from table limit 10;" it threw an error saying sys.column not found.I stopped the monet DB server and tried to restart and restarting the server is failing with error "ERROR: BBPcheckbats : cannot stat file dbfarm\PTMar\bat\73\7323.theap:No such file or directory"

Can anyone please help what is the issue and how to resolve this?

Thanks,
Prashanth.S

Comment: looks like your database is corrupted. Can you retry COPY INTO and then immediately the SELECT query on a new database? ==> that should work.  Further, there exists no MonetDB version 2.0*.  What does `mserver5 --version` say?  And, did you mean `sys.columns?  Because `sys.column` indeed doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi Jennie..thanks for the response.Sorry the version is v11.39.13. and I deleted the dbfarm directory and  reloaded the csv file with copy into and again I encountered same error when I do a select * on the table.Error on mclient is saying unable to find sys.<table name>.<columnname>

Comment: This is strange. COPY INTO is a basic and frequently used function.  Please file a bug report at https://github.com/monetdb/monetdb/issues with (SQL) scripts to reproduce your problem and description of your environment (e.g. OS, versions, what client, etc).